# Netbeans 7.1 Icefaces 3 Modules Installation Error

Tags: netbeans, icefaces

I've installed Netbeans 7.1 and downloaded the icefaces mudules (ICEfaces 3.0.0 project integration plugin for NetBeans 7.1) but when i install the modules i get an error..

Some plugins require plugin J2EE Project Support Utilities to be installed. 
The plugin J2EE Project Support Utilities is requested in implementation version 201112071828. 
The following plugin is affected:       ICEfaces 3

Some plugins require plugin JSF API to be installed. 
The plugin JSF API is requested in implementation version 201112071828. 
The following plugin is affected:       ICEfaces Editor Support

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an application server like Glassfish configured in your Netbeans?

Comment: I've tried with installation of NetBeans 7.1 with Glassfish included.. but.. i get the same error.. by the way i use Tomcat 7.0.22 and Java SE 7u3.

Answer (score 0):

This has been logged as an issue by the ICEfaces support team.  http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-7873

Answer (score 0):

Download this 2 ICEfaces-3.0.0-Netbeans-7.0.x-modules and ICEfaces-3.0.0-Netbeans-7.1-modules
Install ICEfacesLibraries 3.0.0 ONLY from ICEfaces-3.0.0-Netbeans-7.1-modules.

Restart Netbeans.

Then Install ICEfaces 3 Editor Support [7.0.6] from the ICEfaces-3.0.0-Netbeans-7.0.x-modules package(just click continue when asked).

Then  install ICEfaces 3 Framework [7.0.6] from the same package.

If you want you can install all of them from ICEfaces-3.0.0-Netbeans-7.0.x-modules.All this work to me.